# Задачка вывести наибольшее число полином

Tags: javascript

вот код:

```
function Polinom(x){
    x = String(x);
    let arr = x.split('');
    arr = arr.reverse();
    let result = arr.join('');
    if ( result == x ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

var str = [];

for ( let i = 1000; i >= 100; i-- ) {
    for ( let j = 1000; j >= 100; j-- ) {
        if ( Polinom( j * i ) === true ) {
            str.push(Number(j * i));
        }
    }
}

console.log(Math.max(str))
```

не вижу свой ошибки (выводит NaN)

Comment: полином-палиндром - синонимы?

Comment: Что-то в голове не сходится, это задача такая, или ваш подход неправильный... Изначально ищем наибольший палиндром среди произведения целых чисел в двух заданных интервалах (100 - 1000)? И второй момент: Если нужен только максимальный, можно при первом найденном числе - сразу вывести его, и выйти из цикла `break`, а не находить все, потом фильтровать их)

Answer (score 4):

Вы конечно говорите о палиндроме... Функция `Math.max([value1[, value2[, ...]]])` не умеет обрабатывать массивы.

```js
function Polinom(x){
    x = String(x);
    let arr = x.split('');
    arr = arr.reverse();
    let result = arr.join('');
    if ( result == x ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

var arr = [];

for ( let i = 1000; i >= 100; i-- ) {
    for ( let j = 1000; j >= 100; j-- ) {
        if ( Polinom( j * i ) === true ) {
            arr.push(Number(j * i));
        }
    }
}
//----------------------------------------
// Добавить такую функцию в объект Array один из вариантов
//----------------------------------------
Array.prototype.max = function() {
  return Math.max.apply(null, this);
};
//----------------------------------------
console.log(arr.max())
```

---

[Math.max()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)

[Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: Или просто `Math.max(...arr)`

Answer (score 4):

Ошибок несколько.
Первая — Палиндром, а не полином.
Вторая — отсутствие трёх точек для раскрытия массива.

Функция Math.max работает только со списком обычных значений. Чтобы с её помощью отыскать максимальное число в массиве, его нужно превратить в список значений. Пример ниже — работает корректно.

```js
function Palindrome(number) {
  return number == String(number).split('').reverse().join('');
}

const str = [];

for (let number, i = 999; i > 100; --i)
  for (let j = i; j > 100; --j)
    if (Palindrome(number = j * i)) str.push(number);

console.log(Math.max(...str));
```

В третьих — сам алгоритм. Что нужно по задаче? Сформировать массив всех палиндромов в диапазоне? В алгебре есть правило: A * B = B * A. То есть, если мы вычисляем 999 * 111, то нам не нужно затем вычислять 111 * 999. Сейчас в массив записывается много дубликатов чисел. Вряд ли это было нужно. Если же задача найти наибольший палиндром из определённого диапазона, то алгоритм там совсем иной и массив не нужен.